# Access WSO2IS XACML policy with API created in WSO2 API manager. Unable to access XACML policy

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

following this [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Enabling+Role-Based+Access+Control+Using+XACML)

In API Publisher:-

Q1. After step-15 i am confuse to understand first step(Design) and then third step(Manage).

Q2. In first Step(Design) what type of method we have to create like (Post or Get or Put).

Q3. Then after publish i am confuse to test API.

Q4. For testing APIs how will i get Authorization token(API key).

Q5. For testing what should we provide in body.

I am confused above given steps

Answer (score 0):

The confusion is about how to create an API. Basically, you should learn that before trying out XACML or any other advanced features.

Please have a look at the tutorial in [1]. Once you're familiar with the basics, then come to the XACML part. If [1] is not clear to you, please explain which steps are not clear.

After creating an API you need to create an application in API store[2]. Then subscribe the application to the API. The generate keys and invoke the API[3].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Create+and+Publish+an+API

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Subscribe+to+an+API

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Invoke+an+API+using+the+Integrated+API+Console

Comment: As per given link[1] i created and publish api then next step how to test api

Comment: how we will test API

Comment: Next question is i create Post function name validatePolicy in API publisher. when i test it after creating Application in API store same as CheckPhoneNumber with Access Token i get error `<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
  <am:code>0</am:code>
  <am:type>Status report</am:type>
  <am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
  <am:description>Error occurred while evaluating the policy</am:description>
</am:fault>`

Comment: `HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://localhost:9443/services/EntitlementService] javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticatedat sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:431)`

Comment: please update the question with full error trace. what are the port offsets in APIM and IS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186599/discussion-between-bee-and-avinash-tiwari).

Comment: JMSConnectionFactory Error acquiring a Connection from the JMS CF : jmsEventPublisher using properties : {transport.jms.ConcurrentPublishers=allow, java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties, java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.DestinationType=topic, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=TopicConnectionFactory, transport.jms.Destination=throttleData}
javax.jms.JMSException: Error creating connection: Unable to Connect

Comment: Bee i need your help. i having problem here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54186144/unable-to-access-xacml-policy-in-wso2is-5-6-0-from-wso2am-2-5-0-getting-error)