# Unable to access XACML policy in wso2is-5.6.0 from wso2am-2.5.0 getting error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

i following [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Enabling+Role-Based+Access+Control+Using+XACML)

Created XACML policy in wso2is.

Accessing from wso2AM created one POST type function.

While sending request in wso2AM store getting an error

I have update  "jndi.properties" file by commenting second "/test" url line.

After that i am getting error.

> 

```
 ERROR - EntitlementMediator Error occurred while evaluating the policy
org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.proxy.exception.EntitlementProxyException: Cannot initialize EntitlementServiceStub with null Axis2 configuration context.
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.proxy.soap.basicAuth.BasicAuthEntitlementServiceClient.getEntitlementStub(BasicAuthEntitlementServiceClient.java:246)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.proxy.soap.basicAuth.BasicAuthEntitlementServiceClient.getDecision(BasicAuthEntitlementServiceClient.java:122)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.proxy.PEPProxy.getDecision(PEPProxy.java:94)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.proxy.PEPProxy.getDecision(PEPProxy.java:66)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.mediator.EntitlementMediator.mediate(EntitlementMediator.java:185)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:66)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleRequest(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:75)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:325)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:90)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:69)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:303)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:92)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:337)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:383)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2019-01-14 22:28:24,402]  INFO - JMSConnectionFactory JMS ConnectionFactory : jmsEventPublisher initialized
[2019-01-14 22:28:24,429]  INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error occurred while evaluating the policy
[2019-01-14 22:28:25,476] ERROR - JMSConnectionFactory Error acquiring a Connection from the JMS CF : jmsEventPublisher using properties : {transport.jms.ConcurrentPublishers=allow, java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties, java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.DestinationType=topic, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=TopicConnectionFactory, transport.jms.Destination=throttleData}
javax.jms.JMSException: Error creating connection: Unable to Connect
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:346)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:53)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSUtils.createConnection(JMSUtils.java:387)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:268)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory$PoolableJMSConnectionFactory.makeObject(JMSConnectionFactory.java:356)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1181)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.getConnectionFromPool(JMSConnectionFactory.java:286)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSMessageSender.send(JMSMessageSender.java:86)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.JMSEventAdapter$JMSSender.run(JMSEventAdapter.java:284)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.AMQConnectionFailureException: Unable to Connect
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.<init>(AMQConnection.java:485)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:328)
        ... 13 more
[2019-01-14 22:28:25,482] ERROR - JMSConnectionFactory Error acquiring a Connection from the JMS CF : jmsEventPublisher using properties : {transport.jms.ConcurrentPublishers=allow, java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties, java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.DestinationType=topic, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=TopicConnectionFactory, transport.jms.Destination=throttleData}
org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.core.exception.OutputEventAdapterRuntimeException: Error acquiring a Connection from the JMS CF : jmsEventPublisher using properties : {transport.jms.ConcurrentPublishers=allow, java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties, java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.DestinationType=topic, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=TopicConnectionFactory, transport.jms.Destination=throttleData}
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.handleException(JMSConnectionFactory.java:197)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:278)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory$PoolableJMSConnectionFactory.makeObject(JMSConnectionFactory.java:356)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1181)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.getConnectionFromPool(JMSConnectionFactory.java:286)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSMessageSender.send(JMSMessageSender.java:86)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.JMSEventAdapter$JMSSender.run(JMSEventAdapter.java:284)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Error creating connection: Unable to Connect
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:346)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:53)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSUtils.createConnection(JMSUtils.java:387)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:268)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.AMQConnectionFailureException: Unable to Connect
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.<init>(AMQConnection.java:485)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:328)
        ... 13 more
[2019-01-14 22:28:25,486] ERROR - JMSMessageSender
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSMessageSender.send(JMSMessageSender.java:88)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.JMSEventAdapter$JMSSender.run(JMSEventAdapter.java:284)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Am getting above given error. After update "jndi.properties" file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the log you have shared, it looks like there are 2 separate errors in your setup. First one is related to XACML mediator configuration and the second one is related to JMS transport configuration. To understand the problem with the XACML mediator, can you share the mediation extension (synapse) configuration you have used with the API?

For the second error, please share the APIM_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml file and axis2_blocking_client.xml files.

Without looking at these configuration files, it is not possible to provide you with an answer.

Comment: before this problem i have another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370691/unable-to-create-fixed-remote-mounts-in-wso2-api-manager-2-5-0), I am unable to share registry.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54365427/not-able-to-install-xacml-and-xacml-mediation-in-wso2am-2-5-0) i have one more question. how to install XACML and XACML Mediation in WSO2AM-2.5.0.

Comment: [here] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54351535/unable-to-create-access-token-grant-type-in-wso2-api-manager-store-to-test-api)i am able to create access token but that tell invalid token help me in this also.