# How to use WSO2IS for authentication using OIDC and SAML

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am new to WSO2. I want to use wso2is to authentication using OIDC and SAML process. And how to access and display user-profile information in web page.

Answer (score 0):

To try out OpenID connect you could follow the steps mentioned in [1] and to try out a sample you could refer[2]. To get user-profile information you should send a request to user info endpoint or else you could get the user-profile information using the id token. You could refer the doc [2] point 6 for more information.

To use SAML you could refer [3], to get user-profile information you need to enable "Enable Attribute Profile" in your service provider configuration. Please refer doc [3] point 9 " Click here for more information on each attribute" section.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+OAuth2-OpenID+Connect+Single-Sign-On

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Basic+Client+Profile+with+Playground

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Configuring+Single+Sign-On

Comment: i have some another problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54186144/unable-to-access-xacml-policy-in-wso2is-5-6-0-from-wso2am-2-5-0-getting-error) Can u help me to resolve it